# How to go from datetype yyyy-mm-dd to string 'yyyymm' in SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to transform a date to string.

The date type looks as follows:

```
         DATE
2004-06-01 00:00:00.0
```

I want to return

```
         DATE
        200406
```

How could I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read the documentation - [`to_char()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html) and [format models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A)... And are you really sure you want 200401, not 200406?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
To_char(date_column,'YYYYMM') -- or use 'YYYYDD' -- as your expected result is 200401
```

--

```
SQL> with dataa(my_date) as
  2  (SELECT TO_DATE('2004-06-01 00:00:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.#') FROM DUAL)
  3  select to_char(my_date,'YYYYMM') AS DT,
  4   to_char(my_date,'YYYYDD') AS DT1 from dataa;

DT     DT1
------ ------
200406 200401

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Or possibly `to_char(trunc(date_column, 'YYYY'), 'YYYYMM')`, if the 01 is supposed to be the first month of that year, rather than the day part of the date. (Or there other ways of forcing the 01 part of course...) But it's rather unclear what the OP really wants.